# Citing own results which were obtained under former name

Tags: citations, presentation, citation-style, personal-name

I'm giving a talk about results I obtained in my MSc thesis, some time after which I changed my last name. The result will be published under my former name. How should I state it during the talk? I want it both to be clear that this is my result, and that if someone wants to look it up they should do so under the former name.
Since I've seen it's customary to state own results using only the initial:

> Theorem (Y., 2016)

I thought I should write it as:

> Theorem (Y. (under Formername), 2016)

Comment: _The result will be published under my former name._ Why no publish the result under your new name?

Comment: _I've seen it's customary to state own results using only the initial_ I've never seen this style, perhaps it is a convention in your discipline.

Comment: @user2768 I have seen the style fairly often in mathematics (pde, inverse problems) in presentations.

Comment: I'm indeed in mathematics, and that's the way I see most people do in their presentations.

Comment: @user2768 regarding why not publish under the new name - it was submitted for publication before the change, just haven't been published yet. This is also the name which appears on my thesis. And I like the idea of having my former name commemorated in such a way.

Comment: @UrYa'ar If it isn't yet camera-ready, then you might consider publishing under your new name. (There are disadvantages to publishing under different names.)

Comment: For the info provided, you can write whatever. I get just the year anyway. If it is a speech, say "from my thesis. .....".

Comment: @user2768 can you specify some disadvantages? (or link to such a discussion?)

Comment: @UrYa'ar Just search this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Theorem (Y. (under Formername), 2016)

Is fine. (I have personally never seen a paper that *state[s one's] own results using only the initial*. I presume it is specific to the OP's discipline.) Alternatively, *Theorem (Y. (formally Xxx), 2016)* or my preference:

> Theorem (Xxx (now Y.), 2016)

I favour this option because the bibliography will contain *Xxx (2016)*, not *Y. (2016)*. (At least, it won't unless you modify the bibliography.)

Comment: I like your second suggestion, I think I'll use that (if no better suggestion pops-up).